Is there something behind the lava wall in 4-1?
In level 4-1 (Hot Pot) of Penny's Big Breakaway, in the flying section with boost rings near the start of the level, there is a boost ring directly in front of a lava wall. Taking the ring sends me to a hidden passageway behind the lava wall. I've been unable to determine the purpose of this hidden room. Any time I go through it, I seem to hit an invisible wall that gets rid of all my speed before dying from falling.
Is there a purpose to this hidden room behind the lava wall in 4-1? Is it possible to get through without dying?




From what I can tell, there is nothing behind that wall. Going behind the water lavafall will kill the player every time.
